# Pointers to functions

Tags: c++, pointers, boost-bind, boost-function

I have to pass function into pointer. For this purposes I'm using boost::function. The function which catches the pointer is overloaded for different signatures. For example:

```
void Foo(boost::function<int ()>) { ... }
void Foo(boost::function<float ()>) { ... }
void Foo(boost::function<double ()>) { ... }
```

Now I wanna pass some class-method pointer there:

```
class test
{
   public:
      float toCall() { };
};

class Wrapper
{
  Wrapper() {
    test obj;
    Foo(boost::bind(&test::toCall, this));
  }
};


error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo(boost::_bi::bind_t<float, boost::_mfi::mf0<float, test>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<Wrapper*> > >)’
    note: candidates are: Foo(boost::function<float()>&)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nonono this cannot work. Because `boost::function<...>` has a templated constructor to accept any and all types. Compatibility with the call signature is checked later on. Overload resolution cannot resolve this.

Also, i think you want to pass `&obj` instead of `this`. Try converting explicitly:

```
Foo(boost::function<float ()>(boost::bind(&test::toCall, &obj)));
```

This is utterly ugly though so you may want to introduce a typedef

```
void Foo(FloatHandler) { ... }
...
FloatHandler f(boost::bind(&test::toCall, &obj));
Foo(f);
```

Or ultimately you could make `Foo` a template that accepts just any callable type `T`. I suspect that may be the simplest, because in the general case i suspect you don't know to what `boost::function<...>` you need to cast to. And how about folks that want to return a `std::complex<>`. So...

```
template<typename T>
void Foo(T) { ... }
...
Foo(boost::bind(&test::toCall, &obj));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
Foo(boost::bind(&test::toCall, this));
```

`this` is of type `Wrapper`.  But the bind can't find a `toCall` method on it.

Here's a fixed-up version (complete, compiles on g++ 4.3.2) which is probably what you're trying to do:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

void Foo(boost::function<int()>) {}
void Foo(boost::function<float()>) {}
void Foo(boost::function<double()>) {}

struct test {
  float toCall() {return 0.0f;}
};

int main(int,char**) {
  test obj;
  boost::function<float()> tgt=boost::bind(&test::toCall,obj);
  Foo(tgt);
  return 0;
}
```

As AndreyT's answer notes, the return type of bind is... a bit odd, hence the explicit coercion to an appropriate function type.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::bind` does not return a `boost::function` object. It returns an object of *unspecified* type that can be used as a functor with corresponding number of parameters.

While `boost::function` can be conversion-constructed from the result of `boost::bind`, the overload resolution in this case is "too complex" for C++. (Removed my bad example which didn't really illustrate the right problem).

Comment: For boost function, the scenario is even more evil than this. It's like `template<typename T> struct A { template<typename U> A(U); };` now, *that* looks unsolvable to me xD Note that you *can* convert if you had only one function. The difficulty is to *compare* two such conversion sequences. In the boost::function case, this is downright impossible, and in your case, it could be possible but it's too complex for over-res to bother with.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: You are right. My example was illustrating a completely different problem: ambiguity instead of "unsolvability" :)